# Why no immutable set of ints while immutable set of chars is possible?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, integer

```
char *str = "Hey baby";
```

creates memory for the string and points `str` to it. If this is valid, why not the following:

```
int *x = {7, 0, 1};
```

This should do the same, except they are `int`s instead of `char`s.

Comment: Well you can do: int x[ ] = { 7, 0, 1 }; but x is mutable.  Also, `str` really should be: const char *str = "Hey baby";

Comment: @jschultz410 but why not  int *x = { 7, 0, 1 }; ??

Comment: Because the C standard gave special treatment to string literals, because they are so common and useful, but no such notion exists for general array literals.

Comment: This type of "why" question is very hard to answer objectively, since only the designers of the language can give a definitive answer; everyone else would be speculating.

Comment: Though for someone new to a language it is not always clear that it is the whim of the designer that makes something so, so these questions can be valuable for separating "it's mysterious, but this is how" from "no one knows and there is no way".

Comment: Here's another funny tidbit: char str[5] = "Hello"; is legal and won't have a nul terminator while: char str[6] = "Hello"; is also legal but will have a nul terminator.

Answer (score 13):

There is "immutable set of ints", it looks like:

```
(const int[]){7, 0, 1}
```

The proper terminology is *compound literal*. You can point to it:

```
const int *ptr = (const int[]){7, 0, 1};
```

For historical reasons, string literals do not have `const` type despite being immutable. But it is a good idea to use a `const char *` to point to them so that the compiler will detect when you try to write to one.

Compound literals with `const` type may be "collapsed" in the same way that string literals can, i.e. they may overlap with other such compound literals.  Non-const compound literals do have unique addresses and may be written to.

Comment: That's nifty.  When did that get added to C?

Comment: @MattMcNabb sorry, my question is regarding __c90 std__ Does this still hold true ?

Comment: @tomol this was not possible in C90

Answer (score 0):

> Why no immutable set of ints while immutable set of chars is possible?

The reason is that the statements like

```
int *x = {7, 0, 1};
```

is a constraint violation. It depends on compiler how it handles this.

#### 5.1.1.3 Diagnostics (P1):

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined

In most cases compiler doesn't emit any warning if `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` flags are not used to compile. A [bug in GCC](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684635) is reported against this malformed initialization.

An immutable sets of `int` can be created by using `const` qualifier as

```
int const x[] = {7, 0, 1};
```